# How to push to remote repositiorium remove commits?

Tags: git, github

I work on computer and I remove last 3 commits from repositorium due to push --force. I also work on a laptop and I have on the laptop this remove commits. So my question is how can I push from laptop 3 last commits to remote repostitorium ?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how can I push from laptop 3 last commits to remote repostitorium ?

First, it sounds like you're relatively new to git, so a good way to protect yourself from mistakes is to make a copy of your current branch on the laptop. Let's say that the branch with the 3 commits that you want to add to the remote is `myBranch`. Make a new branch starting from that one:

```
git checkout myBranch
git checkout -b myBranch-backup
git checkout myBranch
```

That switches to `myBranch` (in case you're not already there), creates a new branch from the current branch and names it `myBranch-backup`, and then switches back to `myBranch` again.

Next, you'll want to get whatever changes you might have made to `myBranch` on the remote server, and rebase your local `myBranch` onto those changes, which should leave your local `myBranch` with the same history as the remote, plus the 3 extra commits:

```
git fetch myRemote/myBranch
git rebase myRemote/myBranch
```

If all goes well, you'll be left with your 3 extra commits on top of what's in the remote version of the branch. Check that by running

```
git log
```

and confirm that everything looks good. If so, then you can push it back to the remote.